# ./configure can't find C compiler after OS X Lion installation

Tags: xcode, macos, osx-lion, configure

While `cc` and `gcc` are perfectly in their right path (`/Developer/usr/bin` in OS X Lion), running `./configure` tries to compile it through a hard coded (I guess) path - `/usr/bin`.

Where do I setup configure's paths?

Comment: Have you tried `export CC=/Developer/usr/bin/whatever`

Comment: Have you upgraded to Xcode 4.1 or later?

Comment: After upgrading Xcode, I have the same problem.  I noticed /Developer/About Xcode.pdf says "UNIX Development. Command-line tools used for UNIX-based development. Its components are always placed in /usr - only one version installed at a time."

Answer (score 16):

The right answer is to install Xcode 4 from the App Store (free) and then run /Applications/Install Xcode.app.  Then everything you need will be in /usr/.

Comment: Problem is, I've already installed Xcode 4 from the AppStore. Had to symlink /Developer/usr/bin/cc to /usr/bin; but still, ./configure breaks.

Comment: As *njamesp* indicated, there are *two* requirements. (1) Install Xcode 4 from the App Store (which you said you've done). (2) Run `/Applications/Install Xcode.app`. I had the exact same problem you're having, until I did *both* of those things.

Comment: @mivk Not true at all. I have an apple ID, fully working, without a credit card attached.

Comment: @Trezoid: it may also depend on which country you access the site from, and/or which file you want to download. I think I could dl Xcode 3 without adding a CC to my ID, but not Xcode 4.

Comment: I found a slight variation to njamesp's suggestion (I'm using Xcode 4.3).  After installing and launching Xcode, go to Xcode -> Preferences -> Downloads and install the command line tools.  gcc will be at /usr/bin/gcc, symlinked to llvm-gcc-4.2

Answer (score 11):

The best thing to do is actually to download and install the new Command Line Developer Tools package from Apple, which gives you your tools in /usr/bin along with libraries in the proper place and documentation (e.g. manpages).  Either go find it on developer.apple.com or check [here](http://staticimport.blogspot.com/2012/02/mac-os-x-lion-command-line-developer.html) for details and a link.

Comment: Or you can go into Xcode > Preferences > Downloads and click install right after "Command Line Tools"

Answer (score 3):

I just ran into this... I "solved" it by just installing the XCode "Command Line Tools" package

But for some reason it is not possible (for me at least) to reach the same preferences window when a project is open. I had to do the following

- Close XCode (if running)
- Start XCode (do *not* open a project yet)
- Press Command+`,`
- Go to `Downloads`
- Click on `install`

Answer (score 2):

njamesp is correct; the proper solution to your problem is to get your compiler tool chain correctly installed.  But to the question *Where do I setup configure's paths?*, there are a couple of solutions.

1. Pass it to configure as a command line option: `/path/to/configure CC=/p/a/t/h`
2. (Deprecated-bourne shell) Pass it in the environment: `CC=/p/a/t/h /p/t/configure`
3. (Deprecated-csh) `env CC=/p/a/t/h /p/t/configure`
4. setup a config.site.  Put `CONFIG_SITE` in your environment as the path of a file,
   (eg export `CONFIG_SITE=$HOME/config.site`), put `CC=/p/a/t/h` in that file
5. put `CC=/p/a/t/h` in `/usr/local/share/config.site`

All of this assumes that your configure script was generated by autoconf. Options 2 and 3 are discouraged, but if your configure script is ancient option 1 may not work.  Option 5 is flexible, and you can use different config.sites depending on prefix.  $prefix/share/config.site can be used to set options for projects installed in `$prefix`.

Answer (score 1):

Item 1 correct:  I just did the same thing.

> Install XCODE Launch XCODE 
>   Click on Xcode 
>   Choose Preferences 
>   Click on
>   Downloads in the XCode Preference pane 
>   Click on command line tools and
>   click "Install"

The compilers are install in /usr/bin

cd there, and type `"gcc -v"` (without the quotes)and you should get back the following:

```
$ gcc -v
Using built-in specs.
Target: i686-apple-darwin11
Configured with: /private/var/tmp/llvmgcc42/llvmgcc42-2336.11~67/src/configure --disable-checking --enable-werror --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/llvm-gcc-4.2 --mandir=/share/man --enable-languages=c,objc,c++,obj-c++ --program-prefix=llvm- --program-transform-name=/^[cg][^.-]*$/s/$/-4.2/ --with-slibdir=/usr/lib --build=i686-apple-darwin11 --enable-llvm=/private/var/tmp/llvmgcc42/llvmgcc42-2336.11~67/dst-llvmCore/Developer/usr/local --program-prefix=i686-apple-darwin11- --host=x86_64-apple-darwin11 --target=i686-apple-darwin11 --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2336.11.00)
$
```

Answer (score 0):

I recently installed OSX Mavericks and wanted to upgrade to php 5.5.5 and faced a similar issue

```
[user@host /path/to/php5.5.5_src]$ ./configure
checking for cc... cc
checking whether the C compiler works... no
```

Looking at my include path, I noticed that only de base Xcode path was added (I have Xcode 5)

```
[user@host ~]$ cat /etc/paths
/usr/bin
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin
/bin
...
```

All I needed to do is add the path to the Toolchains

```
[user@host ~]$ sudo vi /etc/paths
/usr/bin
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
/bin
...
```

And voilà, it found it.

```
[user@host /path/to/php5.5.5_src]$ ./configure
checking for cc... cc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
```

Hope this helps.