# Unsupported compiler 'com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0' selected for architecture 'x86_64' on Xcode 8.3 beta_2

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode8

I'm annoyed by this error that I'm getting and the fun fact is none of the solutions posted online seem to work for me.

```
Unsupported compiler 'com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0' selected for architecture 'x86_64'
```

Also I found a solution where someone said to change the

```
Xcode > Target > Build Settings > Build Options > Compiler for C/C++/Objective-C

Select Default compiler (Apple LLVM x.y)
```

I cannot find this option, See this:
[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Select the application target rather than project to get the `Compiler for C/C++/Objective-C`.

Comment: How to do that? Please elaborate as I'm new to Xcode.

Comment: In the above image, the left pane shows two images, one is normal Xcode project image and the other is app target image. Select the second one. Also in the left pane it is written Project and Targets, select the one under target.

Comment: I cannot find it in the 'Target' as either. It displays nothing. There is no option to choose.

Comment: Also the error I'm getting is a 'Dependency Analysis Error'

Comment: Can you upload the image where you tried to find the same in the target.

Comment: Sure I'll do that. See the question, I have uploaded it there.

Comment: Okay, my first question would be what is the version of the app. If you have downloaded the app, might be it supports old version of the app. If this is also proper, its better to re-install the XCode again or try installing command line tools for XCode.

Comment: I'm learning swift and I made that app. It was working fine but now it's not. My Xcode started giving me problem just 2 days ago. I don't know why.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6793823/configure-cant-find-c-compiler-after-os-x-lion-installation

Answer (score 0):

If found that on XCode 9.0.1 I had stuck processes from an older version of XCode that were still silently running.  Once I killed these processes, that error message went away.  See my answer here for more details:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/47140402/1461050

Answer (score -1):

The path is right ,after you finder the Build Setting ,just search the compailer,you'll find the Compailer for C/xxxxxx in Build Options